# Dataframe sum(axis=1) is returning Nan Values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I'm trying to make a sum of the second column `('ALL_PPA')`, grouping by `Numéro_département`
Here's my code :

```
df.fillna(0,inplace=True)
df = df.loc[:, ('Numéro_département','ALL_PPA')]
df = df.groupby('Numéro_département').sum(axis=1)
print(df)
```

My DF is full of numbers, I don't have any `NaN` values, but when I apply the function `df.sum(axis=1)`,some rows appear to have a `NaN` Value

Here's how my tab looks like before `sum()`:

[image: Screenshot 1]

Here's after `sum()`

[image: Screenshot 2]

My question is : How am I supposed to do this? I've try to use numpy library but, it doesn't work as I want it to work

Comment: Try to drop the `axis=1`. It's not used in the `sum` function of `groupby`

Comment: I've already tried, it was firstly without the axis=1 , which means that it by default axis=0

Comment: Aside from dropping the `axis=1` (there are no axes in the groupby operation), it looks like column "ALL_PPA" has a mix of strings and numbers. Do `df['All_PPA'] = df['All_PPA'].astype(int)` before the groupby.

Comment: Ok, now it says : invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'ALL_PPA', I don't understand why this errors occurs when there are only digits in my CSV

Comment: The first line in your dataframe is a duplicate of the header. You can delete it before the parsing with `df = df.iloc[1:, :]` or fix whatever caused it in the first place.

Comment: You are insane, thanks a lot mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the first row of that dataframe, as it just as the column names in it, and convert it to an `int`. Right now, it is an object because of the mixed data types:

```
df2 = df.iloc[1:].astype(int).copy()
```

Then, apply `groupby.sum()` and specify the column as well:

```
df3 = df2.groupby('Numero_department')['ALL_PPA'].sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using `.dropna()` before summing the DF will help remove any rows or columns (depending on the `axis=` you choose) with `nan` values. According to the screenshot provided, please drop the first line of the DF as it is a `string`.